# Finding the sum of a list then dividing it with a certain number Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
addDivide n = if sum n / 5 then True else False
```

I am trying to get the sum of a list then see if the sum is divisible by a certain number

eg. [5,5] = 10/5 = 2

Comment: You just need to check if the *remainder* when dividing by 5 is zero or not.

Comment: Minor point: never write `if condition then True else False`, it's equivalent to `condition` alone. Also, `condition` should be a boolean value, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an `Integral` number `a` is dividable by 5, by check if `` n `mod` 5 == 0 ``.

You thus can check this with:

```
addDivide :: (Foldable f, Integral a) => f a -> Bool
addDivide xs = sum xs `mod` 5 == 0
```